# collect <li> elements of <u>l in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have list of ads on my webpage. Those ads are displayed under  tag with id adList. From those ads I want to click on any random ad

So what I have done is as following :

```
List<WebElement> allads = driver.findElements(By.id("adList"));
assertNotNull(allads);
System.out.println(allads.size());
Random random = new Random();
int index = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= allads.size(); i++) {    
      index = random.nextInt(allads.size());
}
allads.get(index).click();
```

But when I run the code no ad is getting clicked and when i checked allads.size() count it is shown as 1 which is wrong as  has multiple ids as following

```
<ul id="adList" data-pageno="2">
<div id="feedList">
<li id="210846759">
<li id="210847160">
<li id="210845605">
<li id="210841804">
<li id="210846830">
<li id="210846163">
<li class="adbannerli">
<li id="210844135">
<li id="210845467">
<li id="210619597">
<li id="200780114">
<script type="text/javascript">
</ul>
```

What should I do to get all li elements and click on any random ad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just try to find the list of `ul` but in fact you need to go more deep and find all `li` elements

```
List<WebElement> allads = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#adList li"));
```